# Is there a python (scipy) function to determine parameters needed to obtain a target power?

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy

In R there is a very useful function that helps with determining parameters for a two sided t-test in order to obtain a target statistical power.

The function is called `power.prop.test`.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/power.prop.test.html

You can call it using:

```
power.prop.test(p1 = .50, p2 = .75, power = .90)
```

And it will tell you n the sample size needed to obtain this power. This is extremely useful in deterring sample sizes for tests.

Is there a similar function in the scipy package?

Comment: I think it would be [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) if there is.

Comment: That function is also written in pure `R` so by calling it without `()` will show the source code.  The port to numpy will be straight forward if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thanks @Justin this helped in creating the below.

Comment: Thanks @Raufio I used the page you linked to to find the isf function below.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've managed to replicate the function using the below formula for n and the inverse survival function `norm.isf` from scipy.stats

[image]

```
from scipy.stats import norm, zscore

def sample_power_probtest(p1, p2, power=0.8, sig=0.05):
    z = norm.isf([sig/2]) #two-sided t test
    zp = -1 * norm.isf([power]) 
    d = (p1-p2)
    s =2*((p1+p2) /2)*(1-((p1+p2) /2))
    n = s * ((zp + z)**2) / (d**2)
    return int(round(n[0]))

def sample_power_difftest(d, s, power=0.8, sig=0.05):
    z = norm.isf([sig/2])
    zp = -1 * norm.isf([power])
    n = s * ((zp + z)**2) / (d**2)
    return int(round(n[0]))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = sample_power_probtest(0.1, 0.11, power=0.8, sig=0.05)
    print n  #14752

    n = sample_power_difftest(0.1, 0.5, power=0.8, sig=0.05)
    print n  #392
```

Comment: Have you considered donating this to SciPy? It's surely a useful function to have.

Comment: You need to sign up at GitHub, then fork [their repo](https://github.com/scipy/scipy), put your changes in and submit a pull request. (Unfortunately, the SciPy developer documentation is a bit of a mess at present...)

Comment: Thanks @larsmans I'm on github so I'll fork and do just this. Cheers

Comment: This looks really promising. Any chance you can address @erikwestlund's answer below?

Comment: I assume that: 
(d = difference of means) and (s = difference of std).

But what are p1 and p2?

Comment: @MattAlcock Can you add a reference to the screenshot of the formula?

Answer (score 18):

Some of the basic power calculations are now available in statsmodels

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/stats.html#power-and-sample-size-calculations
http://jpktd.blogspot.ca/2013/03/statistical-power-in-statsmodels.html

The blog article does not yet take the latest changes to the statsmodels code into account. Also, I haven't decided yet how many wrapper functions to provide, since many power calculations just reduce to the basic distribution.

```
>>> import statsmodels.stats.api as sms
>>> es = sms.proportion_effectsize(0.5, 0.75)
>>> sms.NormalIndPower().solve_power(es, power=0.9, alpha=0.05, ratio=1)
76.652940372066908
```

In R stats

```
> power.prop.test(p1 = .50, p2 = .75, power = .90)

     Two-sample comparison of proportions power calculation 

              n = 76.7069301141077
             p1 = 0.5
             p2 = 0.75
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.9
    alternative = two.sided

 NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

using R's `pwr` package

```
> library(pwr)
> h<-ES.h(0.5,0.75)
> pwr.2p.test(h=h, power=0.9, sig.level=0.05)

     Difference of proportion power calculation for binomial distribution (arcsine transformation) 

              h = 0.5235987755982985
              n = 76.6529406106181
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.9
    alternative = two.sided

 NOTE: same sample sizes
```

Comment: Something is wrong with this, the answers produced vary depending on whether you use R or Python, especially when you vary the ratio.  Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: It's R `stats` and Stata versus R `pwr` and statsmodels. See https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1197 and associated mailing list thread for details. I don't remember where SAS is in this.

Answer (score 10):

Matt's answer for getting the needed n (per group) is almost right, but there is a small error.

Given d (difference in means), s (standard deviation), sig (significance level, typically .05), and power (typically .80), the formula for calculating the number of observations per group is:

```
n= (2s^2 * ((z_(sig/2) + z_power)^2) / (d^2)
```

As you can see in his formula, he has

```
n = s * ((zp + z)**2) / (d**2)
```

the "s" part is wrong. a correct function that reproduces r's functionality is:

```
def sample_power_difftest(d, s, power=0.8, sig=0.05):
    z = norm.isf([sig/2]) 
    zp = -1 * norm.isf([power])
    n = (2*(s**2)) * ((zp + z)**2) / (d**2)
    return int(round(n[0]))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

You also have:

```
from statsmodels.stats.power import tt_ind_solve_power
```

and put "None" in the value you want to obtain. For instande, to obtain the  number of observations in the case of effect_size = 0.1, power = 0.8 and so on, you should put:

```
tt_ind_solve_power(effect_size=0.1, nobs1 = None, alpha=0.05, power=0.8, ratio=1, alternative='two-sided')
```

and obtain: 1570.7330663315456 as the number of observations required.
Or else, to obtain the power you can attain with the other values fixed:

```
tt_ind_solve_power(effect_size= 0.2, nobs1 = 200, alpha=0.05, power=None, ratio=1, alternative='two-sided')
```

and you obtain: 0.5140816347005553